# Multiple users mounting a shared server utilizing Git

Tags: git, nfs, sshfs

I am wondering if this type of setup would be good for Git. We have a server that contains source code, when we make code changes it must also be tested on this server. To avoid pulling the code locally making changes, syncing back up to the server for testing and then committing, we are wondering if we can mount the server locally.

Our concern is that git will track changes of all users since we are sharing the same (mounting the same) repository. Is there a way we can set this up and have Git track each users change independently, possibly through ssh-keys?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way we can set this up and have Git track each users change independently, possibly through ssh-keys?

Yes, providing you use the git wrapper I wrote, [`VonC/gitw`](https://github.com/VonC/gitw)

It uses the [`SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120081/7490) and ask you, at the first git command, who you are.
Then, for the rest of the session, all your git command will be done with the proper [`GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`/`GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_committing).
If you are connecting from the same fixed IP, you won't even been asked who you are at your next SSH session.

That way, each use makes commits with their proper `user.name`/`user.email`.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out and congrats on 1mil rep! Trying the install your wrapper on centos and have a few follow up questions. From the install guide there is one step that I don't quite understand "put the gitw generate in the previous step" could you elaborate more on this? Additionally I was also looking through the shell script and noticed a few interesting commands "ok" "error" and "info" as these are not recognized by centos can I simply change them to echo?

Comment: @gitquestion926 The `build.bat amd` executed on a PC (with Go installed) will have generated the `gitw` binary.

Comment: @gitquestion926 And I just pushed the missing `echos` file: a simple git pull, and those `ok`, `error` and `info` will work!

Comment: Ohh I see the confusion I looked at them as if they were separate install instructions. Do you know which version of GO you used to compile? I just installed go1.15.6 on my windows but when I run `build.bat amd` I'm seeing `usage: link  [options] main.o` . There is also a line before it stating `not a git repository`, it did successfully download `go-prompt` `sys` `term` and `go-runewidth`

Comment: @gitquestion926 Did you clone the repository? Di you launch `build amd` from within that clone repository folder?

Comment: Yes, here is a screenshot of the output I'm seeing. https://imgur.com/a/aUMsybi

Comment: @gitquestion926 `gitw-master` does not look like the name of a cloned repository, but rather an archive of the project uncompressed: if you don't see a `.git` subfolder in that `gitw-master`, he build won't work.

Comment: @gitquestion926 You need to `git clone https://github.com/VonC/gitw` and `cd gitw`

Comment: My mistake, thank you for all the troubleshooting help. I'm unfortunately  still seeing an issue that I think may have to do with the go version? Here is a new output https://imgur.com/a/cgJtSyY One thing I noticed is that after the clone I don't see a .git folder .  On the screenshot the clone is on the left and the build is on the right

Comment: @gitquestion926 Left side looks good. Right side should work. I am using Go 1.15.3. Try and replace the first line of `build.bat` by `@echo on`, and grab a screenshot of what the build does.

Comment: Here is a screenshot using go1.15.6 with echo on https://imgur.com/a/RE1TOkD

Comment: @gitquestion926 Right! I see.... the locale used will make the commands time and date return a different value which means the day/hours are not properly parsed

Comment: @gitquestion926 Can you uncomment line 18 (remove rem) and comment line 19 (rem). line 22, replace dtStamp24 by dtStamp9.